# hazelcast writing to 2 cache from 1 mapstore

Tags: java, hazelcast, distributed-caching

I have some data in the database I want to read into 2 cache:
1.  Entire json representing row of data
2.  Just a subset of columns for quick querying purposes

I have a MapStore for persistence to the first cache with the json.  I am thinking of using an EntryListener on the main json cache so when we add a value there, the entry listener will then write to the other cache.  Does this approach sound like a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have the second map just for querying purposes. You can use [Indexes](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#indexing-queries) or even a [Continuous Query Cache](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#continuous-query-cache) on the first map and not have a second map at all.

Comment: A continuous query cache filters rows only but not columns right?

Comment: That's correct, in that case that wouldn't help, but if you want to return only a subset of fields you can use Projections in combination of Predicates as well. Please remember to index the fields you want to query. https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#projections

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sounds ok. Just note that it is better to off-load the logic in the EntryListener to another thread, not to block eventing threads in Hazelcast when you perform long-running operations in listeners.

You can also think usage of interceptors: https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#adding-interceptors Again, you need to off-load the logic also for interceptors as I mentioned above.